# Laravel Livewire error when I add a constructor to call a service class

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I've got a piece of code I want to reuse. I've read this [Laravel cleaner code](https://medium.com/swlh/laravel-cleaner-code-46203ca3ee4d) article and this other [Laravel Services Pattern](https://blackdeerdev.com/laravel-services-pattern/) article, where I have realized I can reuse code in several places of the application by using services classes.

In this case, I created a new `MyService` class, inside a new folder `app/Services/MyService`.

```
namespace App\Services;

class MyService
{
    public function reuse_code($param){
       return void;
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I want to call the class through the constructor inside a Livewire class component, as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Services\MyService;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class LivewireTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    private $myClassService;

    public function __construct(MyService $myService)
    {
        $this->myClassService = $myService;
    }

    public function render()
    {
       $foo = $this->myClassService->reuse_code($param);
       return view('my.view',compact('foo'));
    }
}
```

The error displayed is the following:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Livewire\LivewireTable::__construct()
> must be an instance of App\Services\MyService, string given

(However, If I use a trait, there are no problems. But I am afraid then my traits collide as previous experiences)

How do I fix it? What am I missing?

Comment: how are you calling the Livewire class? Have you tried using `mount()` instead of `__construct()`?

Comment: Indeed, [in the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#parameters) it says so! That did the trick. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solved**
Just like [@IGP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4339402/igp) said, reading in the [livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#parameters) it says:

> In Livewire components, you use mount() instead of a class constructor
> __construct() like you may be used to.

So, my working code is as follows:

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    
    use App\Services\MyService;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Livewire\WithPagination;
    
    class LivewireTable extends Component
    {
        use WithPagination;
    
        private $myClassService;
    
        public function mount(MyService $myService)
        {
            $this->myClassService = $myService;
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
           $foo = $this->myClassService->reuse_code($param);
           return view('my.view',compact('foo'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes when you're inside livewire component you can inject service class using `mount()` method.

Answer (score 9):

> Livewire's boot method Runs on every request, immediately after the component is instantiated, but before any other lifecycle methods are called

Here's the solution worked for me.

```
public bool $checkAllRecords = false;

public array $checkedRecords = [];

private MailService $service;

public function boot(MailInterface $service)
{
    $this->service = $service;
}

public function updatingCheckAllRecords($value)
{
    $this->checkRecords = $value ? (array) $this->service->getListData($this->perPage, $this->search)->pluck('id') : []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `public function boot()` method to the component can be useful for things like initializing protected properties, which do not need to be persisted between requests. Below is an example of initializing a protected property as an Eloquent model from the Livewire documentation:

```php
use Livewire\Attributes\Locked;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Post;
 
class ShowPost extends Component
{
    #[Locked]
    public $postId = 1;
 
    protected Post $post;
 
    public function boot() 
    {
        $this->post = Post::find($this->postId);
    }
 
    // ...
}
```

[See https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/lifecycle-hooks#boot](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/lifecycle-hooks#boot)